# Increasing the colour of dots according to density

Tags: python, numpy, colors, statistics, scatter-plot

I have a 2D point cloud that I displayed with scatter and a probability distribution on these points. Is there a quick way on Python to colour the points in relation to my distribution (the higher the mass in a point, the more accentuated the colour is)?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: if you estimate the distribution using the points, then I think the distribution value at each point is a good measure for density and you can pass it as the argument `c` in scatter to specify color of the points.

Comment: you could just map the colour alpha(opacity) values to the probability density values